# Opening multiple terminal tabs and running specific commands on project open in IDE

Tags: server, ide, client

Briefly

Since the structure of my projects repeats itself, I want to write a script so that when opening a project in the IDE (no matter which one), I have several tabs open in the terminal, a templated path is inserted into them and certain commands are run. Can someone please tell me at least which way to look?

In detail

I am writing a frontend and backend (NextJS, Test Js) and the following structure is repeated from project to project — in each project I have a client and server folder in the root directory. I also open 4 terminal tabs (2 for the frontend and 2 for the backend). In 1 (clietn) and 3 (server), I run the client and server respectively. In 2 (client) and 4 (server), I manually run secondary scripts (installing dependencies, working with git, etc.). I would like to automate the process so that when I open the project, the directory opens immediately in the first two tabs./client, and in the last two directories ./server. I also need the startup scripts (yarn dev and yarn start: dev) to be run in tabs 1 and 3, respectively.

I couldn't find a similar case on Google